# Deleting cards from Balanced via Ruby gem

Tags: payment, credit-card, balanced-payments

I'm marking cards as invalid by doing a `PUT` request with the `is_valid` parameter being set to `false`. Is `is_valid` ever set server side such as in the case of a card being declined by the processor? If Balanced sets `is_valid` to `false` will this be a permanent state or is it possible that it will be transient e.g. if there are low funds in the account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is_valid` is solely a user set value.

Balanced will not mark a card as invalid if it fails payment authorization as this could be a transient state as you mention.

If you wish to filter out valid cards from invalid you can do something like this:

```
cards = Balanced::Card.all(is_valid: true)
```